# Res value is null in an app.get call done from vue.js front-end to express back-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am calling this code from the front-end and confirmed that there is a proper db connection and that the Id value is properly passed, and that there is a corresponding value in the database, but for some reason, res is null. What am I missing?

```
app.get("/api/walletlogin/user/:userId", (req, res) => {

 id = req.params.userId
 var query = {_id: id}
  db.collection("Users").findOne(query, (err, result) => {
  if (result) {
    console.log(result.userName)
  } else {
    console.log('No User')
  }
})
```

Here is the front-end call:

```
  axios.get('/api/walletlogin/user/' + accounts)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('Logged in With ' + accounts)
        router.push('/account')
      })
      .catch((errors) => {
        console.log('Cannot log in')
      })
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err, 'err!!')
  })
```

Comment: please dont use `res` as callback argument name while you already have an `res`, use `result` instead

Comment: Thank you Ifaruki. I have changed the res to result, as above, but that did not solve the issue, It is still null.

Comment: What is the output when you print `result` only ? Not `result.userName`.

Comment: you dont use mongoose right?

Comment: Also, which `res` do you mean is `null` ? The Response object, or the response from the database ?

Comment: If I print console.log(result), the value is null. No, I do not use mongoose. The value from "result" is null, not the one from res.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to convert your id to an objectID.

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId; 
var id = ObjectId(req.params.userId);
```

Comment: Thank you Ifaruki. It doesn't appear that this solution works. I am obtaining the following error: "Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters"

Comment: how does your `userId` looks like if you console.log it?

Comment: Well, after adding your modification, I am not able to print it out, for I am receiving the error mentioned. Before, it was a simple string without any additional characters.

Comment: I am terribly sorry Ifaruki. You are right, there was a typo in the Database value. So sorry and thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @JF0001 no problem, nothing to sorry about

Comment: Actually, to be more specific, the value that is passed from the front-end is a cryptocurrency address. For some reason, some of the characters passed were upper-case, while the same address had been stored in the database with these same characters as lower case. I will add a solution to this post for anyone who would encounter this issue in the future. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

to search by id, you must use the **ObjectID** class from the **mongodb** package. Here is an example invented by me, it does not reflect the real work, but I hope it will become clear on it:

```js
const { ObjectID } = require('mongodb');

const id = '5ee4f69bfa0b960de8aec158'; // in your example is req.params.userId
db.collection('users').findOne({ _id: new ObjectID(id)}, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
    console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: Thank you Rustam for your contribution. I have tried your solution but I am obtaining the same error as the solution proposed by Ifaruki: "Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters".

Answer (score 0):

I am adding the details of the issue initially encountered in case someone else would experience it in the future. The value that is passed from the front-end is a cryptocurrency address. For some reason, some of the characters passed were upper-case, while the same address had been stored in the database with these same characters as lower case. Thus, one needs to add code to make sure that the case of the letters found in the respective addresses is ignored.

J